# Using exceptions to return exceptional values: is this good practice?

Tags: python, exception

Is it good Python practice to have a function return None most of the time, while *exceptionally* returning useful *values* by *raising an exception where the values are stored*?

I am a little uneasy with this because exceptions are most often used to signal some kind of problem, with some attributes of the exception giving some details about the problem. Here, I would like the exception to actually mean "here is an exceptional *result* of this function".

Using an exception for this is tempting because (1) this is only done in exceptional circumstances and (2) this is efficient, in Python (more than an `if … is not None:…`). On the other hand, the exception itself is not the sign of an error of any sort, just a vehicle for the exceptionally returned values.

Is there any official recommendation against using exceptions for exceptionally returning values from a function?

**PS**: Here is a use case:

- An object method updates the internal state of the object based on new data (it's a finite state automaton).
- At some point (usually after getting many data points), the method considers that some action must be taken (in my case: some date from the object should be stored in a database, and the object's state is reset to the initial state, where it is ready to get more data).

Thus, the sequence of events, for the method, is: get data, update state, get data, update state,… ah! we reached an special state where information about the object should be stored! reset the objet's state and send the relevant information out; get data, update state, get data, update state,… Thus, most of the time, the function updates the internal state of the object and does not return anything. Exceptionally, it must send important information about the object.

Comment: Could you give a concrete code example of when you might want to do this?

Comment: Exceptions model.. exceptions to the normal flow. Use it for any out-of-band communication that makes sense. The Exception object itself is a value too!

Comment: IMO, in your use case, the method should either return a bool that means "I need flush and reset", or it should automatically do the flush and reset internally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exceptions can model *any* exception to the normal flow of the code. Errors are the most common use-case, but anything where the *normal* return type doesn't really make sense can be seen as an opportunity to raise an exception instead.

Raising an exception for non-error use-cases is *perfectly fine*, if it simplifies your flow.

Remember, the `Exception` object raised and caught, is itself a value. Attaching information to that is a perfectly acceptable method to communicate with a caller to signal a deviation from 'normal'.

I'd prefer an exception over a sentinel value like `None`; it makes the handling explicit, and can actually lead to cleaner handling and better feedback to a developer when they forget to handle the exceptional return value. If your code normally returns a list, but in specific, exceptional circumstances, you return `None`, *and the caller doesn't handle it*, then you get weird bugs down the line somewhere. `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` is a lot more cryptic than an explicit unhandled exception.

Comment: Can you provide a \*\*nearly\*\* real-world example?

Comment: @frostnational: the `requests` library makes raising an exception for non-2xx or 3xx response codes optional. If you do raise an exception, the request is still accessible as an attribute on the exception object.

Comment: @frostnational: and then there's [`GeneratorExit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.GeneratorExit).

Answer (score 1):

In the exceptional case where there's a result, will you normally want to process the result at the point of call? In that case, exceptions are unnecessary; just return the value. At point-of-call, the difference is:

```
result = yourFunction()
if result is not None:
    handleExceptionalResult(result)
```

versus

```
try:
    yourFunction()
except ExceptionalResult as result:
    handleExceptionalResult(result)
```

The first is much clearer to me.

Comment: The first example is indeed more readable in languages _without good exception handling_. The use of exceptions really shines when you get to choose at what level in the call-stack you actually handle the exception. Your first example falls down when you can't handle the exception there and resort to the C idiom `if(func() == -1) return -1;` where you have to chain error returns up arbitrarily high.

Comment: Agreed, which is why I'm asking if the exception is handled at point of call.

Comment: +1 because this is a lucid description of a possible handling of the situation, but I do find the second version clearer: it shows explicitly that the exceptional behavior is exceptional. In addition, it is more efficient, in Python.

Comment: I don't think it's more efficient. I did a quick `dis.dis()` of both a model function that raises vs one that returns, and the two calling sequences I show above. The raising function has to construct an exception object in addition to preparing whatever information needs to be returned, and the catching function has additional work to do to set up the exception.

Comment: @RussellBorogove: I just did a timing test between the `if` and the `try` approaches (with `timeit`, with `yourFunction()` returning `None`, i.e. the common case), and they have very similar running times. However, the `if` test is very simple, in my particular case, but is in general slower (like membership testing in a mapping, or even a list, etc.). Maybe this is what the official documentation means when it claims that exceptions are "[clean and fast](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)".